# How to change background-color of a paragraph in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, background-color

```js
let n = 5;
let m = 5;
for(let j=0; j<m; j++){
for(let i=0; i<n; i++){
let boite = document.createElement("p");
boite.innerHTML = i+1;
  
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(boite);
 
}
 
document.write("<br>");
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
p{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I'm trying to change the `background-color` of a paragraph in yellow when the number is even (so, in **javascript**).

I believe i have to write a condition with as a result something like

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

but i don't know how to select the paragraph as i don't want the `backgroundColor` of the `body` to change

Comment: what do you mean with pair? when i == j?

Comment: i mean when i%2 == 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a condition as follows

```
if((i+1)% 2 == 0){}
```

```js
let n = 5;
let m = 5;
for(let j=0; j<m; j++){
for(let i=0; i<n; i++){
let boite = document.createElement("p");
boite.innerHTML = i+1;
if((i+1)% 2 == 0){
//voir si i+1 est pair ajouter le couleur
boite.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
boite.style.color = "#000";
}
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(boite);

 
}
 
document.write("<br>");
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
p{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: thank you ! exactly what i needed. Next step is to improve my english, i guess...

Comment: and give me an up vote and mark it as answred ^^', mark ma réponse comme solution merci

Comment: i did, but my reputation is <15 so it told me than it doesn't count (sorry)

Comment: thank you, wish you all the best and welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Just give each paragraph a separate id then get the element's id then change it's style like this:
`document.getElementById("ID").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";`

Comment: fact is (sorry i didn't precise) i can only use css and javascript, so no html

Answer (score 0):

To change the bacgkround color of a paragraph just use following:

```
<body>
      <p id="paragraphToChange">Hello World!</p>
<script>
    document.getElementById("paragraphToChange").style.background  = "blue";
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: fact is (sorry i didn't precise) : i can only use css and javascript...

Comment: This is only HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The second part would be to create a conditional function that triggers the background change when you want it.

Comment: the question has been answered ! still thank you for trying to help me

Comment: jQery would simplify yor effort a lot:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_even.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```js
let docBody = document.querySelector("body");
let n = 6;
let m = 6;
for (let j = 1; j < m; j++) {
  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    ifEven = (!(i % 2)) ? "style='background-color:yellow;color:#000;'" : "";
    docBody.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p " + ifEven + ">" + i + "</p>");
  }
  docBody.children[docBody.children.length - 1].insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<br>");
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

p {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```